# Balsamic vinegar reduction

Tags: storage-lifetime

The balsamic vinegar reduction that I made a few months ago has solidified. It has been refrigerated. Can I heat it to liquefy it and still use it?

Comment: When you say solidified, do you mean it's too thick to use or that it's actually solid? If it's the former, I'd start by letting it come up to room temperature. If it's the latter, I'd add a small amount of water to rehydrate it.

Comment: @DebG, there isn't enough information in your question. What exactly have you made and what is its purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Balsamic vinegar should not need storage in a refrigerator, just in a cupboard away from light and in an air tight container.

I would warm the balsamic vinegar by leaving it to warm in at room temperature, covered with a tea towel. If you want to speed up this process I would suggest putting it into a pan or warm water and then reduce it again.