# Balsamic vinegar became too thick. How to liquefy it?

Tags: storage-lifetime, vinegar

I store an Italian balsamic vinegar ([BVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balsamic_vinegar_of_Modena)) in a fridge and use it from time to time for a couple of years. It used to be thick and viscous. (In contrast to some [other reports](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/77808/balsamic-vinegar-reduction), I did not need to reduce it, as the original consistence was totally satisfying.) But now it has almost solidified:

[image: balsamic vinegar]

How to make it liquid again?

Comment: Does it change as it warms? You don't need to keep balsamic in the fridge, btw, the pantry is good for 3 - 5 years for 'commercial' balsamic & up to 20 years for the 'good stuff'.

Comment: A little water would thin it of course.

Comment: As it warms, it becomes more liquid. However, some solidified pieces still remain. It looks like that would take several days for them to "melt".

Answer (score 1):

I would use some good regular (i.e., a non-reduced or a non-aged) balsamic vinegar to thin it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try placing the jar in hot water or use warm running tap water to heat up and re-liquefy the vinegar.

When I have honey that has crystalized and I want it in liquid form, I heat water in a pot, take the pot off the burner, and place the (glass) honey jar in the pot until it is the correct consistency.